# nginx reverse proxy redirect returns incorrect URL

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, jira

I am setting up JIRA Software in a Docker container. JIRA is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080. I have my reverse proxy on https://hostname/jira redirecting the traffic using this config:

```
location /jira {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host               $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;
proxy_redirect   off;
}
```

The problem is that I get a 302 redirect loop. When I visit https://hostname/jira I get redirected to https://hostname/jira/jira/secure/SetupMode!default.jspa over and over again. That would be the correct URL except for the extra "/jira" fragment.

Comment: I have since added the statement "rewrite ^/jira(/jira/.*) $1 last;" directly before the location block, but it appears to have no effect on the behavior. Now I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 0):

> That would be the correct URL except for the extra `/jira` fragment.

Rather than using `location /jira`, you might consider adding your proxy as a sub-domain in a new server block e.g.:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  jira.hostname;

    location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host               $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;
       proxy_redirect   off;
       }
}
```

If you decide to try this, don't forget to update any appropriate DNS records (or similar) to point `jira.hostname` to the correct IP (e.g. *127.0.0.1*).